# ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.396.24.02: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just updated my nvidia GPU driver and got this error when i import tensorflow like that:

`import tensorflow as tf`

Config:
Ubuntu 16.04

NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]

16GB RAM

i7 6700HQ

Python 3.5.2

GCC 5.4.0

Cuda 9.0.176

Tensorflow 1.8

CudNN 7

This error had no result on Google ...
Maybe i should downgrade any version like my GPU driver or update CudNN ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-396` fixed it

now i have another error

Answer (score 0):

When I had that error it was due me trying to update a driver, and tensorflow was still looking for the original one.
Try:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot now
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot now
```

It's probably overkill, but this made tensorflow update the file it was looking for, and I could import again. This worked for me, I can not guarantee that it will work for you.